# Sort data file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I am using sort in a bash script to order a file generated. An example of an input file is :

```
2,0,2165,5
2,-10,2122,5
2,10,2830,6
2,-11,2121,5
2,11,2903,6
2,-1,2151,5
2,1,2171,5
2,-12,2114,5
2,-13,2118,5
2,-14,2121,5
2,-2,2144,5
2,2,2199,5
```

I need sorting on the first number and then the second, I tried the following:

```
sort -k1,1n -k2,2n data
```

The positive numbers are ordered as required, but the negative ones are dictionary ordered:

```
2,-10,2122,5
2,-11,2121,5
2,-1,2151,5
2,-12,2114,5
2,-13,2118,5
2,-14,2121,5
2,-2,2144,5
2,0,2165,5
2,1,2171,5
2,2,2199,5
2,10,2830,6
2,11,2903,6
```

Could anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 4):

```
sort -t, -k1,1n -k2,2n nums
2,-14,2121,5
2,-13,2118,5
2,-12,2114,5
2,-11,2121,5
2,-10,2122,5
2,-2,2144,5
2,-1,2151,5
2,0,2165,5
2,1,2171,5
2,2,2199,5
2,10,2830,6
2,11,2903,6
```

You need to tell sort the delimiter, and it works here.